# Is there a way to connect Firestore Database through REST API without using Auth 2.0 authentication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, postman, rest

I am trying to follow this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) to get my firestore collections and documents in postman.

When I send this request

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project-id}/databases/(default)/documents/{document-id}'
```

I get an empty object.

My challenge is I have failed to get the access token without implementing the sign with the feature.

Comment: "I have failed to get the access token without implementing the sign with the feature." => What do you exactly mean? Where is the corresponding code? Which error do you get that shows a failure? Also, note the example in the doc you refer to: `/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA`there is one collection ID (`cities`) and one document ID (`LA`). You only have `{document-id}`: it seems you miss a collection...

Comment: I think that @RenaudTarnec is right you need to put the document ID so you can get the data in the fields, you can try I executing the request [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/get)

Comment: `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prep-a4175/databases/ChatSessions/documents/Fx75kqqpYnAYr74Cnob2`  this is the link am using, where `"prep-a4275"` is the project id, `"ChatSessions"` is the collection and `"Fx75kqqpYnAYr74Cnob2"` is the document id. but this throws `"Database name 'ChatSessions' not found. Please use your project's default database: '(default)"` error.  that's why had replaced the database name with (default)

Comment: When I tried in the api that I shared before after ```databases/``` you need to put ```(default)```, in your case you need to add it before ```ChatSessions```

Comment: Thank you very much, I also had to pass a key get parameter containing my wen ap key